# Override WhatsApp contact image with the chosen Contact Image

Tags: images, profiles, whatsapp-messenger

I dislike how people use full body pictures for their contact images when it's a small image. When I link the accounts in my Android, I chose a picture that looks good and helps me identify them easily. But in WhatsApp, when these people chose their profile picture, they override my selection.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Probably related: [How to change someone's profile picture in WhatsApp?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105329/how-to-change-someones-profile-picture-in-whatsapp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now there isn't, unless an add-ons for WhatsApp will enable this or they built it in themselves. It's comparable to Facebook, user set their own avatar and this can be seen by friends.
This works unlike your contact list in which you control the content and other users have no say in adjusting the content.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way. You can just download Android SDK and do from the console:

`adb push /tmp/newimage.jpg /data/data/com.whatsapp/files/Avatars/XXXXXX@s.whatsapp.net.j`

where `XXXX` is the phone number and `/tmp/newimage.jpg` is the new image you want to replace it with.

Comment: You forgot to mention that directories below `/data/data` are only writable by their resp. owners. So what you recommend would only work if the device were rooted AND the `adbd` (ADB daemon) on the device running in "insecure mode" (i.e. with full root privileges).

Comment: As Useless said The device should be only rooted you can just use root explorer, copy someone else's picture file and rename it to target number, it works great.. directory: "/data/data/com.whatsapp/files/Avatars/"