# How to change someone's profile picture in WhatsApp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, photos, editing, contact-photo

I don't like one of my WhatsApp friend's picture (we chat regularly, though the photo disgusts me), so I want to change his profile picture.

I did change its source image, but it didn't work on the small image that you see on the chat screen next to the name. Is it possible to change it? If it's how?

Comment: Probably related: [Override WhatsApp contact image with the chosen Contact Image](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24977/override-whatsapp-contact-image-with-the-chosen-contact-image)

Comment: Simply ask him to change the profile picture..

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](https://techgradeindia.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/how-to-change-your-friends-whatsapp-dp-display-profile-picture-using-your-phone/) out. To summarize the steps in the link:

1. Resize the pic you want to use to 561×561.
2. Save it in `/sdcard/WhatsApp/Profile Pictures` on your phone.
3. Then rename it to your friend's phone number, including country code first. (If Jenny lived in Manhattan, her filename would be 12128675309.jpg)
4. Reopen WhatsApp and the picture should be there.

Comment: I already did it, but it only changes it when you tap for the bigger image. Small image stills same. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I'm not able to test it at the moment so I don't know if it'll help, but did you try clearing the WhatsApp cache?

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work at all. For large or small images. One thing I noticed is that the path mentioned doesn't exist on my phone. Firstly, my WA seems to be in internal storage. Then, the path of /Profile Pictures doesn't exist, but /Media/WhatsApp Profile Photos exists, so I put it in there, to no avail. It should also be noted that there were no other photos in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you have root access. WhatsApp profile pictures are now saved under

```
/data/data/com.whatsapp/cache/Profile Pictures/
```

(earlier `Internal Storage/WhatsApp/media/WhatsApp Profile Pictures`)

Profile pictures are saved with their respective phone number. Just change the picture with the exact name. Done.

However, this will get refreshed very soon. To prevent this change the image permissions to read-only with any file explorer.