# Whatsapp Profile Pictures folder missing

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have a peculiar scenario with the Whatsapp Profile Pictures folder. Previously the Profile Pictures of contacts which I view used to get stored inside Whatsapp Profile Pictures folder. One day an error message (I presume) got popped up and I pressed OK without reading the message. From then the folder went missing but I am able to view the pictures even if the mobile is offline. Don't know where it is now saving the images. I have also checked if the folder was hidden. Even if I recreate the folder it is not storing the images in that folder. I have also reinstalled the application. Does whatsapp store the images in any other format or location other than storing in the default folder.

Answer (score 5):

WhatsApp no longer caches/stores the viewed profile pictures under `/sdcard/WhatsApp/Profile Pictures/` directory, due many reasons, **[like this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105329/how-to-change-someones-profile-picture-in-whatsapp)**..
Now, it's stored under its own app cache area in /data partition.

If you're rooted, then head over to the directory: `/data/data/com.whatsapp/cache/Profile Pictures/`.
There, you'll find the cached profile pictures (that you have viewed).

If you're not rooted, as others have said, you need to explicitly save the profile picture from the WhatsApp app by clicking the pic, click again to enter full screen, click the '**Share**' icon and press '**Save to Gallery**'.

Now the saved profile picture can viewed in the directory: `/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Profile Photos/`

Comment: Sharing user photo saved it in whatsapp images /sent/ folder for me

Answer (score 0):

I think I have exactly the problem (except I don't recall getting any error message), the folder in Whatsapp\Profile Pictures is just gone. What I've figured out is that now you'll have to manually save a contact's profile picture, i.e. after the picture is loaded, you'll have to keep pressing on it. It'll open up the picture and then you can save it. It'll be in Whatsapp\Media\Profile Photos. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the Profile picture of any person in the WhatsApp; you will able to see the Share symbol at Top - Right of the screen.

Click on it and you will be asked to share with lots of Apps; but at the top you will have "**Save to Gallery**" -- you can select this option and the Profile picture will be saved in the folder --> media >> WhatsApp Profile