# I don't want to see DP of a particular contact on Whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I don't want to see the DP of a contact on Whatsapp without blocking them.

Can anyone help in getting that done?

Please note. I have an Android phone Samsung S8.

Thanks

Comment: What does DP mean?

Comment: DP means Display pic or Profile Photo

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](https://techgradeindia.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/how-to-change-your-friends-whatsapp-dp-display-profile-picture-using-your-phone/) out. To summarize the steps in the link:

1. Resize the pic you want to use to 561×561.
2. Save it in `/sdcard/WhatsApp/Profile Pictures` on your phone.
3. Then rename it to your friend's phone number, including country code first. (If Jenny lived in Manhattan, her filename would be 12128675309.jpg)
4. Reopen WhatsApp and the picture should be there.

Comment: That used to be possible until WhatsApp hid the profile picture folder. Now it's not possible.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you can try this same procedure in the directory mentioned here if you're rooted: *[Whatsapp Profile Pictures folder missing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148642/whatsapp-profile-pictures-folder-missing/154864#154864)*