# WhatsApp data directory is empty

Tags: root-access, whatsapp-messenger, profiles

I wanted to know where does WhatsApp store its profile pictures so I searched on google and found this [article](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148642/whatsapp-profile-pictures-folder-missing#:%7E:text=WhatsApp%20no%20longer%20caches%2Fstores,%2Fcache%2FProfile%20Pictures%2F%20.). The top answer of the above article said that WhatsApp stores its profile pictures in `/data/data/com.whatsapp/cache/Profile Pictures` directory. I used [JRummy Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.root.browserfree) to view the above mentioned directory. When I went to `/data/data/com.whatsapp` directory, it was empty. There were no files or folders. So am I doing something wrong or WhatsApp stores those pictures somewhere else? If you know the answer, please write it. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Is your phone rooted?

Comment: Yes it is rooted.

Comment: Wait, I just checked and found that it is not rooted. Should it be rooted to view that folder?

Comment: Can you view the contents of others (app) folders in '/data/data/`?

Comment: No all the directories in the "/data/data/" folder are empty

Comment: To view those folders you need root access. Without it, there is no way to check their contents.

Comment: And how to get Root access?

Comment: You can view questions related to [root-access](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/root-access) or use your favorite search engine. You have to search for your apps that can root your phone, install it and the drivers on your PC, and follow the instructions of those who have done it before. Just know that if things go wrong, the phone can be bricked.

Comment: Can't I just check the data folder without rooting my phone? Because, as far as I have read, rooting may trigger privacy and security issues.

Comment: If you just want the image file of someone's profile picture it might be easier to open it in the app and use the share button to "share" the image into a file manager app like Total Commander, from where you can save it to your internal storage. That way you don't need to root your device.

Comment: I don't want to store them. I want to see where (in the system) are they stored. I've got my answer. So thank you all for your kind support ☺️.