# Hide someone's profile picture in WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Is it possible to change or hide my friend's profile picture in WhatsApp? I have tried many ways but still no result.

Comment: Related: [How to change someone's profile picture in WhatsApp?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/105329), [Override WhatsApp contact image with the chosen Contact Image](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24977)